# Jupyter Notebook failed command in Anaconda Prompt for Qiskit

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, qiskit

I have Qiskit installed via Anaconda and a virtual environment set up in Python 3.8. when I run `(.venv) C:\Users\brenm>jupyter notebook` (in Anaconda prompt) it fails and throws `'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

To counter this, I ran `(.venv) C:\Users\brenm>python -m pip install jupyter --user` and jupyter notebook installed properly. But when I run `jupyter notebook`in the Anaconda prompt, it still throws `'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I'm very confused as to what is happening because I believed jupyter notebook was a Qiskit dependency that was supposed to be installed already. More so, I'm confused why when I manually install jupyter notebook, the command `jupyter notebook` is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sure that your Python library path is in your system variables , you can try this command :
`python -m notebook`